# JDK 8 is not pointing to a correct path

Tags: java, visual-studio, java-8

using visual studio code and getting the error (java 8 is not installed) i have it installed and i set the path `setting.json` for `java.home` to

```
{
    "java.home": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_241"
}
```

It says the path is not pointing to a jdk.

Comment: How did you get those backslashes there? This Windows business is a little bit crazy; use forward slashes instead: `"java.home": "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_241"` :mind_blowing:

Comment: @x80486 just did it, still giving me the same error :(

Comment: What's the output for `which java` on the console?

Comment: Error: could not open `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_241\lib\i386\jvm.cfg'

Comment: Well, `Program Files (x86)` is different from `Program Files`; you need to make sure that location exists first, hence the `which java` — although you may not have `which`, depending on the console you are using.

Comment: not really sure what you are saying, i moved it back to progam files (x86) and changed the name back to jre and still getting the same error. Please rephrase
Error C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_241) does not point to a JDK.